# How to disallow nested comments in antlr

Tags: comments, antlr

I currently have a multiline comment lexer rule in antlr which looks like:

```
MULTILINE: '/*' .* '*/' {$channel=HIDDEN;} ;
```

However, this currently allows things like:

```
/* /* hello */ */
```

Is there any possible way to disable nesting comments in antlr? I've tried various things like

```
MULTILINE: '/*' (~(MULTILINE)|.*) '*/' {$channel=HIDDEN;} ;
```

But that doesn't work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not correct: `.*` and `.+` are not greedy.

Given the parser generated by the following grammar:

```
grammar T;

parse
 : (t=. {System.out.printf("\%-15s'\%s'\n", tokenNames[$t.type], $t.text);} )* EOF
 ;

MULTILINE
 : '/*' .* '*/' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
 ;

OTHER
 : .
 ;
```

the input `"/* /* hello */ */"` would produce the following on your command line:

```
OTHER          ' '
OTHER          '*'
OTHER          '/'
```

I.e., `"/* /* hello */"` is being put on the `HIDDEN` channel, and 3 `OTHER` tokens are constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

It is not possible for the prefix nor suffix to be recognized in the comment body.  Also, nesting is not allowed.

```
COMMENT_NON_NEST
    : '/*'
      ( ('/'|'*'+)? ~[*/] )*?
      ('/'|'*'+?)?
      '*/'
      {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```